# Item packing optimization for delivery

Tags: algorithm

I am just starting my adventure with programming and I encountered a problem that I am not sure if my way of thinking is correct so I seek advice.

We have N items with a volume of x_n (let's say there are 5 items with volume 1, 2, 3, 3 , 100 etc). As a  delivery company we only have trucks with empty space of number 5*k-1 (like 4, 9 ...). I need to find the best way to put those items into trucks to minimize empty space after. I can use as many trucks as I need with any volume I want.

Of course if all items fit in one truck (like in an example above 1+2+3+3+100=109=22*5-1) it is easy but when it's not working I was thinking of taking the biggest item and fitting it into the smallest possible truck (putting 100 into 104 truck) and then thinking of this truck as a one with 4 free space and then taking another bigger one and so on so on.

Is it a good idea or maybe there is someting i missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your algorithm does not work. Consider the case you have only items with 100 and 9. You start by fitting the 100 into a 104 sized track, then 9 does not fit so you get another track with size 9. You are left with 4 empty spaces, when you could use only one track with size 109.

I think a little simplification is in order here. Notice that we only care about the remainders of the volumes modulo 5 (with a small exception - if we only have volumes of size `5k` then modulo 5 we have only zeros, but we still need one track, and we'll have 4 free spaces. Any other case we can just add all 5s to some track and they won't affect the free spaces). We can also ignore all the 4s (in modulo), as each of them can be put in its own track. We are now left with 1s, 2s and 3s. We can stack pairs of 2s together and pairs of 1-3 to tracks so that we are left only with at most one 2, and only 1s or only 3s. Furthermore, if we still have 1s, we can stack quartets of them to tracks and if we still have 3s we can stack triplets of them to tracks. We are left with one of the following options:

1. Nothing is left, or a 2 and two 1s - In this case no free space is left.
2. Only a 3 is left, or three 1s, or a 1 and a 2, or two 3s and a 2 - In this case one free space is left.
3. Only a 2 is left, or two 1s - In this case two free spaces are left.
4. Only a 1 is left, or two 3s - In this case three free spaces are left.
5. Only a 3 and a 2 are left, or three 1s and a 2 - In this case four free spaces are left.